# Pass Activity to service or use BroadCast

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have a local `Service` and  an `Activity`. I want to pass `Activity` object to `service`, so when `Activity` is bound to my `Service`, I can call function `activty.doSomething()`. Should I do it? I know that I can use `BroadcastReceiver` to call `doSomething()` from `Service`, but comparing with the above idea, what is the best way to do? Pass `activity` to `service` or use `BroadcastReceiver`? Thank everyone!

```
// This is MyActivity, where I will pass `activity` to `service` when `service` 
//  is bound or when activity is resumed. I will clear the `activity` object 
//  in `Service` when `Activity` is paused.
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    LocalService mService; // this is my 

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        if(isServiceBound){
            mService.setActivity(this);
        }
    }

    public void onPause(){
        if(isServiceBound){
            mService.setActivity(null);
        }
    }

    // Do something here
    public void doSomething(){
    }

    //Code to start, bind service, unbind ... go here

}

public class LocalService extends Service{
    MyActivity mActivity;
    public void setActivity(MyActivity a){
        mActivity = a;
    }
    // Start service, do something here
}
```

Comment: use BroadcastReceiver, your activity may be finish in middle of your service and it cause to null pointer exception

Comment: no, I think I can check for null whenever I use my activity!

Answer (score 1):

Binding the activity to the service is a more flexible option for local services, since you can implement a rich api in both directions. Check the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

On the other hand, BroadcastReceiver is a better option for intentservices, because they expire as soon as they finish their job.

Remember also that if you want your service to persist, you have to start it explicitly with startService, otherwise it will be killed when the number of bound activities goes to 0.